# "Row Before" in a sorted query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to find a row immediately before and after a given row, with a `order by` clause.  The use case is "previous entry" and "next entry" links in a vaguely blog-like system.  The engine is MySQL 5.6. The table schema is

```sql
CREATE TABLE `weekly_notes` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `year` int(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `week_number` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `header_text` text NOT NULL,
  `image_filename` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `boundry_image_filename` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=0 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

and the query is ordered by `year desc, week_number desc`.  The criteria for selecting a row is year and week_number.

Sample Data

```sql
insert into weekly_notes values
    (101,2018,53,'Week 53 from year 2018',NULL,NULL),
    (102,2019,50,'Week 50 from year 2019', NULL, NULL),
    (103,2019,51,'Week 51 from year 2019', NULL, NULL),
    (104,2019,52,'Week 52 from year 2019', NULL, NULL),
    (105,2020,1,'Week 1 from year 2020', NULL, NULL),
    (106,2019,53,'Week 53 from year 2019', NULL, NULL),
    (107,2020,2,'Week 2 from year 2020', NULL, NULL),
    (108,2020,3,'Week 3 from year 2020', NULL, NULL),
    (109,2020,4,'Week 4 from year 2020', NULL, NULL);
```

The select criteria are year an week, so I would like to be able to select the week "before" 2020-01 and get the row for 2019-53 or the week before 2020-03 and get the row for 2020-02

Comment: Before which row?

Comment: It would be before a year and week, so in pseudo-SQL
```
Select * from weekly_notes where BEFORE(week=9, year=2020)
```
or something like that

Comment: Please show us sample data and expected results to clarify your question. Also, which version of MySQL are you running?

Comment: Note the number in parentheses following an INT declaration has very little meaning, and is probably best omitted

Comment: Updated with sample data and more clarity about the select criteria

Comment: @AaronMacks: thanks. It would probaby be helpful for you to provide the result that you expect, as tabular text.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lag()` -- on however you are defining the ordering.  For instance, if you wanted the row after a certain `header_text`:

```
select wn.*
from (select wn.*,
             lag(header_text) over (order by year, week) as prev_header_text
      from weekly_notes wn
     ) wn
where prev_header_text = <what you are looking for>
```

This assumes that "after" is chronological.  I suppose "after" with a descending sort could actually mean the row *before*, in which case you would use `lead()` instead of `lag()`.

For before a particular week/year combo, you can use:

```
select wn.*
from (select wn.*,
             lag(week) over (order by year, week) as prev_week,
             lag(year) over (order by year, week) as prev_year
      from weekly_notes wn
     ) wn
where prev_week = @week and prev_year = @year
```